# Debugging macro definition in cross-platform project

Tags: c, windows, macros, cross-platform

In our cross-platform c-project we are using the macro for the logging purposes:

```
#if _WINDOWS
    #define DEBUG_PRINTF(x) KdPrint(x)
#endif
```

The `DEBUG_PRINTF` usage example:

```
DEBUG_PRINTF(("Message with param (%s)\n", pString)); //            (1)
DEBUG_PRINTF(("Message with no param\n")); //                       (2)
```

It is ok. According to the [KdPrint function reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff548092(v=vs.85).aspx) a  call to KdPrint requires double parentheses:

```
KdPrint (( Format, arguments ))
KdPrintEx (( DPFLTR_DEFAULT_ID, DPFLTR_INFO_LEVEL, Format, arguments ))
```

My question is how to deal with already existed macros such as `(1)` and `(2)` by porting the `DEBUG_PRINTF` on other platform such as linux in *userspace*?

For example the definition

```
#if defined (__LINUX__)
    #define DEBUG_PRINTF((x)) fprintf(stderr, x)
#endif
```

does not compile for macros such as `(1)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it the other way around:

```
#if _WINDOWS
    #define DEBUG_PRINTF(x) KdPrint((x))
#else
    #define DEBUG_PRINTF(format, ...) fprintf(stderr, format, ##__VA_ARGS__)
#endif
```

Usage:

```
DEBUG_PRINTF("Message with param (%s)\n", pString);
```